# Unity3d Pause Button doesn't pause game onClick()

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I've made a unity3d game and I want to add UI . I've started with a pause button but it doesn't seem to work.
Here is the button info:
[image: button info]

I've created an uiManager script to manage the button , as shown in the image above and here is the code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class myUIManager : MonoBehaviour {


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void Pause() //Function to take care of Pause Button.. 
    {

        print("Entered Pause Func");
        if (Time.timeScale == 1 && paused == false) //1 means the time is normal so the game is running..
        {
            print("Enterer first if");
            Time.timeScale = 0; //Pause Game..
        }

        if (Time.timeScale == 0)
        {
            Time.timeScale = 1; //Resume Game..
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the canvas screenshot :
[image]

Any ideas? I've been searching for hours ..

Comment: Do you see *"Entered Pause Func"* in the Console tab when you press the button?

Comment: @Programmer yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in your `Pause` method:

```
public void Pause() //Function to take care of Pause Button.. 
{

    print("Entered Pause Func");
    if (Time.timeScale == 1 && paused == false) //1 means the time is normal so the game is running..
    {
        print("Enterer first if");
        Time.timeScale = 0; //Pause Game..
    }

    if (Time.timeScale == 0)
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1; //Resume Game..
    }
}
```

If you enter the first `if` statement you set `Time.timeScale = 0` - and then you immediately go into the second `if` and set it back to 1.

Try this - it `returns`s from the `Pause` method once it sets the `Time.timeScale` to 0.

```
public void Pause() //Function to take care of Pause Button.. 
{

    print("Entered Pause Func");
    if (Time.timeScale == 1 && paused == false) //1 means the time is normal so the game is running..
    {
        print("Enterer first if");
        Time.timeScale = 0; //Pause Game..
        return;
    }

    if (Time.timeScale == 0)
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1; //Resume Game..
    }
}
```

If the only two things you want to do in your `Pause` method are to set the `Time.timeScale` to 0 or 1, you could even simplify it to this:

```
public void Pause() //Function to take care of Pause Button.. 
{

    print("Entered Pause Func");
    if (Time.timeScale == 1 && paused == false) //1 means the time is normal so the game is running..
    {
        print("Enterer first if");
        Time.timeScale = 0; //Pause Game..
    }
    else
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1; //Resume Game..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if the condition of your first `if` statement is `true` then you set your `timeScale` to `0` then the condition of the second `if` becomes `true` then you set it back to `1`
 You should just change your second `if` to an `else if` so that if the first condition is `true` then your program wont check the second one.

```
 public void Pause() 
    {
        if (Time.timeScale == 1) 
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        }
       else if (Time.timeScale == 0)
        {
            Time.timeScale = 1; //Resume Game..
        }
    }
```